# Is it possible to make all the children of a `flex-flow: column` flexbox the same height as the tallest child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have a flexbox that is styled with `flex-flow: column`, and that container has five child `div` with variable heights, is it possible to make all the children be the same height as the tallest?

I'm not necessarily looking to fill the container with them (i.e. have them fill any excess space), just all be the same height.

In the snippet below, the five child `div` all have different content, which causes them to be different heights; is it possible to make all five be as tall as the uppermost `div`, which has the most content?

```css
html {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  background: firebrick;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 30rem;
}

.panel {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.panel:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam pariatur commodi ipsum ex quam eius voluptatibus fugit vero, consectetur explicabo cum magni fugiat natus.</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="panel">this is a test</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, commodi a!</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Saepe, nihil pariatur enim, porro temporibus harum, quo omnis beatae eaque soluta totam ipsa?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: refer to this, its' very clear https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "no". Flexbox distributes space among flex items based on the size of the container, not the size of a particular sibling. You'll need to use a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind them stretching to fit container height you can set children `flex-basis` to 20%:

```css
html {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  background: firebrick;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 30rem;
}

.panel {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.panel:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam pariatur commodi ipsum ex quam eius voluptatibus fugit vero, consectetur explicabo cum magni fugiat natus.</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="panel">this is a test</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, commodi a!</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Saepe, nihil pariatur enim, porro temporibus harum, quo omnis beatae eaque soluta totam ipsa?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see its set to 20% because there are 5 panels, right?

Comment: This solution doesn't address the problem, which is *to make items equal the height of the tallest sibling*.

Comment: @Raqem Exactly, if this is not a nice solution for you, you probably need to use javascript to dynamically get the tallest panel height and set all panels that high

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `flex-basis`, with the catch that you have to know how many children there will be. You can also use `flex-grow`, but that only distributes the extra space available, so the tallest elements will still be taller than the shorter ones:

```css
html {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  background: firebrick;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 30rem;
}

.panel {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
flex-basis: 20%;
}

.panel:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam pariatur commodi ipsum ex quam eius voluptatibus fugit vero, consectetur explicabo cum magni fugiat natus.</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="panel">this is a test</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, commodi a!</div>
  <div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Saepe, nihil pariatur enim, porro temporibus harum, quo omnis beatae eaque soluta totam ipsa?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't address the problem, which is *to make items equal the height of the tallest sibling*.